# ggplot2 loop graph with conditional subsets

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, subset, apply

**Data description:**

I have a data set that is in long format with multiple different grouping variables (in data example: StandID and simID)

**What I am trying to do:**

I need to create simple scatter plots (x=predicted, y=observed) from this dataset for multiple columns based on a unique grouping variable.

An example of what I am trying to do using just standard plot is

```
obs=subset(example,simID=="OBS_OBS_OBS")
csfnw=example[example$simID== "CS_F_NW",]

plot(obs$X1HR,csfnw$X1HR)
```

I would need to do this for all simID and columns 9-14. (12 graphs total from data example)

**What I have tried:**

The problem I am running into is the y axis needs to remain the same, while cycling through the different subsets for the x axis.

I will admit up front, I have no idea what would be the best approach for this... I thought this would be easy for a split second because the data is already in long format and I would just be pointing to a subset of the data.

1) My original approach was to try and just splice up the data so that each simID had its own data frame, and compare it against the observation dataframe but I don't know how I would then pass it to ggplot.

2) My second idea was to make some kind of makeGraph function containing all the aesthetics I wanted essentially and use some kind of apply on it to pass everything through the function, but I could get neither to work.

```
 makePlot=function(dat,x,y) {
 ggplot(data=dat,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point(shape=Treat)+theme_bw()
}
```

What I could get to work was just breaking down the dataframe into the vectors of the variables I would then pass to some kind of loop/apply

```
sims=levels(example$simID)
sims2=sims[sims != "OBS_OBS_OBS"]
fuel_classes=colnames(example)[9:14]
```

**Thank you**

**Data example:**

```
    example=structure(list(Year = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
"2013", "2014", "2015"), class = "factor"), StandID = structure(c(10L, 
2L, 6L, 22L, 14L, 18L, 34L, 26L, 30L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 22L, 14L, 
18L, 34L, 26L, 30L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 22L, 14L, 18L, 34L, 26L, 30L
), .Label = c("1NB", "1NC", "1NT", "1NTB", "1RB", "1RC", "1RT", 
"1RTB", "1SB", "1SC", "1ST", "1STB", "2NB", "2NC", "2NT", "2NTB", 
"2RB", "2RC", "2RT", "2RTB", "2SB", "2SC", "2ST", "2STB", "3NB", 
"3NC", "3NT", "3NTB", "3RB", "3RC", "3RT", "3RTB", "3SB", "3SC", 
"3ST", "3STB"), class = "factor"), Block = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"
), class = "factor"), Aspect = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "R", "S"), class = "factor"), 
Treat = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("B", "C", "T", "TB"), class = "factor"), 
Variant = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CS", "OBS", "SN"), class = "factor"), 
Fuels = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "NF", "OBS"), class = "factor"), 
Weather = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NW", "OBS", "W"), class = "factor"), 
X1HR = c(0.321666667, 0.177777778, 0.216111111, 0.280555556, 
0.255555556, 0.251666667, 0.296666667, 0.231111111, 0.22, 
0.27556628, 0.298042506, 0.440185249, 0.36150676, 0.398630172, 
0.367523015, 0.345717251, 0.349305987, 0.412227929, 0.242860824, 
0.258737177, 0.394024998, 0.287317872, 0.321927488, 0.281322986, 
0.313588411, 0.303123146, 0.383658946), X10HR = c(0.440555556, 
0.32, 0.266666667, 0.292222222, 0.496666667, 0.334444444, 
0.564444444, 0.424444444, 0.432777778, 0.775042951, 0.832148314, 
1.08174026, 1.023838878, 0.976997674, 0.844206274, 0.929837704, 
1.0527215, 1.089246511, 0.88642776, 0.920596302, 1.209707737, 
1.083737493, 1.077612877, 0.92481339, 1.041637182, 1.149550319, 
1.229776621), X100HR = c(0.953888889, 1.379444444, 0.881666667, 
1.640555556, 2.321666667, 1.122222222, 1.907777778, 1.633888889, 
1.208333333, 1.832724094, 2.149356842, 2.364475727, 2.493232965, 
2.262988567, 1.903909683, 2.135747433, 2.256677628, 2.288722038, 
1.997704744, 2.087135553, 2.524872541, 2.34671092, 2.338253498, 
2.06796217, 2.176314831, 2.580271006, 2.857197046), X1000HR = c(4.766666667, 
8.342222222, 3.803333333, 8.057777778, 10.11444444, 6.931111111, 
6.980555556, 13.20611111, 1.853333333, 3.389177084, 4.915714741, 
2.795267582, 2.48227787, 2.218413353, 1.64684248, 2.716156483, 
2.913746119, 2.238629341, 3.449863434, 3.432626724, 3.617531776, 
3.641639471, 3.453454971, 3.176793337, 3.459602833, 3.871166945, 
2.683447838), LITTER = c(2.4, 2.219444444, 2.772222222, 2.596666667, 
2.693888889, 2.226111111, 2.552222222, 3.109444444, 2.963333333, 
2.882233381, 3.025934696, 3.174396992, 3.291081667, 2.897673607, 
2.737119675, 2.987895727, 3.679605484, 2.769756079, 2.882241249, 
3.02594161, 3.174404144, 3.291091681, 2.897681713, 2.737129688, 
2.987901449, 3.679611444, 2.769766569), DUFF = c(1.483333333, 
1.723888889, 0.901666667, 1.520555556, 1.49, 1.366111111, 
0.551666667, 1.056111111, 0.786111111, 2.034614563, 2.349547148, 
1.685223818, 2.301301956, 2.609308243, 2.21895647, 2.043699026, 
2.142618418, 0.953421116, 4.968493462, 4.990526676, 5.012362003, 
5.023665905, 4.974074364, 4.947199821, 4.976779461, 5.082509995, 
3.55211544), simID = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("CS_F_NW", "CS_F_W", 
"CS_NF_NW", "CS_NF_W", "OBS_OBS_OBS", "SN_F_NW", "SN_F_W", 
"SN_NF_NW", "SN_NF_W"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Year", 
"StandID", "Block", "Aspect", "Treat", "Variant", "Fuels", "Weather", 
"X1HR", "X10HR", "X100HR", "X1000HR", "LITTER", "DUFF", "simID"
), row.names = c(37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 
130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were actually on the right track. If all plots are the same, just make one function and then use loops to loop over the subsets. For your example this can be done like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
# the plot function
plotFun = function(dat, title) {
  ggplot(data=dat) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), shape=18) + 
    ggtitle(title) +
    theme_bw()
}
# columns of interest
colIdx = 9:14
# split on all values of simID
dfList = split(example, example$simID)
# simID has never appearing factors. These are removed
dfList = dfList[lapply(dfList, nrow) != 0]
# make empty array for saving plots
plotList = array(list(), dim = c(length(dfList), length(dfList), length(colIdx)),
                 dimnames = list(names(dfList), names(dfList), names(example)[colIdx]))
# the first two loops loop over all unique combinations of dfList
for (i in 2:length(dfList)) { 
  for (j in 1:(i-1)) {
    # loop over target variables
    for (k in seq_along(colIdx)) {
      # store variables to plot in a temporary dataframe
      tempDf = data.frame(x = dfList[[i]][, colIdx[k]],
                          y = dfList[[j]][, colIdx[k]])
      # add a title so we can see in the plot what is plotted vs what
      title = paste0(names(dfList)[i], ":", names(dfList[[i]])[colIdx[k]], " VS ",
                     names(dfList)[j], ":", names(dfList[[j]])[colIdx[k]])
      # make and save plot
      plotList[[i, j, k]] = plotFun(tempDf, title)
    }
  }
}
# call the plots like this
plotList[[2, 1, 4]]
# Note that we only filled the lower triangle of combinations
# therefore indexing with [[1, 1, 1]] just returns NULL
plotList[, , 1]
```

This process can probably be more optimized, but when creating graphs I would go for clarity above speed since speed usually isn't an issue.

Comment: I thought there would be a nested loop in there somewhere but could not figure out how it would work. 

one additional question: How would I approach keeping the Y axis constant? 
I am essentially looking to make all the plots in column 5. 
if I pull out the observed variables into a new variable 
    (dfList$OBS_OBS_OBS) 
 
I feel like I would then need to pull out the y from the TempDF into the previous loop circuit somehow? or am I just changing the referencing in the tempDF to 
    y=obs$something?

Comment: You can use the function `scale_y_continuous(breaks = ...)` in the plotfunction to give every plot the same y axis. I don't understand your second question, do you mean you only want to make `plotList[, 5, ]`?

Comment: yes, I am trying to make plotList [,5,], for a total of 8*6 plots